# TFS merge after move+delete combo

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, merge

Short version:

if files under TFS source control are moved, and their original folder is deleted in the same changeset, is it possible to merge the moves to another branch in a proper way ?

Long version:

My code's parent branch was thoroughly refactored: all files got moved individually, and the files' original parent folders were deleted rather than moved:

Before refactoring:

```
ParentBranch   / OriginalParentFolder / Subfolder1 / File1
                                      / Subfolder2 / File2
```

After refactoring:

```
ParentBranch   / RefactoredParentFolder / File1
                                        / Subfolder3 / File2
               / ---OriginalParentFolder---
```

Moving the files and deleting the original folders occured in one changeset.
So, the files in the parent branch still have their history; but if I merge now to a child branch, the deletion of the folder seems to take precedence over moving the files, discarding all changes, and ignoring the relationship between the files:

Before merge:

```
ChildBranch / OriginalParentFolder / Subfolder1 / ModifiedFile1
                                   / Subfolder2 / ModifiedFile2
```

After merge:

```
ChildBranch / RefactoredParentFolder     / File1
                                         / Subfolder2 / File2
            / ---OriginalParentFolder--- / ---Subfolder1--- / ---ModifiedFile1---
                                         / ---Subfolder2--- / ---ModifiedFile2---
```

I've tried multiple approaches to try and get the modifications in File1 and File2 moved to their new destinations, but I always end up with either the nonmodified files only, or two seperate versions of the files.

Apart from rolling back the parent branch, and trying again (without the folder deletes), is there any chance the moves could be merged with the child branch modifications ?

Thanks,

Bart

Answer (score 0):

You could undo the deletion of the original folder in the refactored solution and merge then delete the original folder after the merge.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this already, but unfortunately after undelete of the folder, the files in the folder are still merged as "deleted" rather than "moved"...

Comment: Are you trying to show as "moved" so it retains the file  history?

Comment: I'm trying to get my changes on those files merged with the changes in the refactored files. Normally, this would work automatically, but the parent delete prevents this from happening even after rolling back that delete, since the original changeset with the move+delete marked everything under the original folders as deleted.

Comment: I think your best bet is to undo the restructuring in the refactored code, merge and then restructure.